# fail at react start script

Tags: reactjs, npm

I work on a React project within the Intellij IDE. But my project fails when I try to start it with npm start. The error code tells me that the critical point is the starting of the start script in the *package.json*.

I already tried the most often given advice here: reinstall node.js, node_modules. But this does not work for me.

Thank you already for looking at my problem.

Here is the error code in the terminal.

```
VXN5155:dhbw-engineering ThomasA$ npm start

> dhbw-engineering@0.1.0 start /Users/ThomasA/Desktop/Uni/3semester/Sw-:Webengineering/ProjektPraxisSwEngineering/dhbw-engineering
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! dhbw-engineering@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the dhbw-engineering@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ThomasA/.npm/_logs/2020-09-17T08_03_23_911Z-debug.log
```

**Edit:** Below are the scripts defined in the `scripts` section of my *package.json*:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

Comment: Try either `npx react-scripts start` or `npm react-scripts start`

Comment: npx react-scripts start works for me. Thank your very much!

npm react-scripts start did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run `chmod +x node_modules/.bin/react-scripts`.

Then run `npm start`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with `npm start` in react project just after `create-react-app`.

I fixed it by:

- Creating **.env** file in my react app root directory.
- Then adding **SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true** to the **.env** file.
  This fixed the problem.

Then `npm start` or `yarn start` it should work.